# Check CSV for object not matching?

Tags: powershell, csv, if-statement, powershell-3.0, verification

Probably a really elementary question but preliminary searches didn't return much. I'm writing a script that takes `$CSC` (which is user input) compares it to a .csv object called "CSC" and then populates the relevant information based off that.

```
$CSC = "1100 4WWW"   #Hardcoded value to test against #CSC are always <#### #ChChCh>
$roster = Import-Csv <my path>

Foreach ($row in $roster) {
    If ($CSC -eq $row.CSC) { 
        $Department = $row.Department
        $Division = $row.Division
        $Street = $row.Street
        $City = $row.City
        $State = $row.State
        $Zipcode = $row.Zipcode
        $OfficePhone = $row.Phone
        $Country = $row.Country
    } Else {    }
}
```

That's working fine but how would I check if a user input $CSC didn't match an  in the list?

Making the else or making an elseif `($CSC -ne $row.CSC)` obviously returns a value for every line except the matching one. I'm guessing I should use a nested if statement but being self taught I wasn't sure what the best way to do this is. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us the definition of/assignment to `$CSC`? Is it a single integer? An array of integers? A string? Also `$roster` and a short CSV sample might be useful

Comment: `$id -notin $roster.CSC`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I understand the way I wrote it was confusing. Updated for clarity. I don't think the CSV contents is really relevant since I'm already using it correctly in the `If` statement and my question about the logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of a couple things you can do.

Option 1: Using the `-match` operator. [not recommended as it has some regex constraints but I will present it as an option anyway]

```
$CSC = "1100 4WWW"   #Hardcoded value to test against #CSC are always <#### #ChChCh>
$roster = Import-Csv <my path>

if ($roster -match $CSC)
{
    Foreach ($row in $roster) {
        If ($CSC -eq $row.CSC) { 
            $Department = $row.Department
            $Division = $row.Division
            $Street = $row.Street
            $City = $row.City
            $State = $row.State
            $Zipcode = $row.Zipcode
            $OfficePhone = $row.Phone
            $Country = $row.Country
        } Else {    }
    }
}
else
{
   #your 'not a match' code goes here
}
```

Option 2: Set a flag

```
$CSC = "1100 4WWW"   #Hardcoded value to test against #CSC are always <#### #ChChCh>
$roster = Import-Csv <my path>

$flag = $false
Foreach ($row in $roster)
{
    If ($CSC -eq $row.CSC)
    { 
        $Department = $row.Department
        $Division = $row.Division
        $Street = $row.Street
        $City = $row.City
        $State = $row.State
        $Zipcode = $row.Zipcode
        $OfficePhone = $row.Phone
        $Country = $row.Country

        $flag = $true
    }
    Else {    }
}

If (!$flag)
{
    #your 'not a match' code goes here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried the second one earlier but wasn't sure if that was a good way to go about it.